# How can I debug remotely

Tags: linux, debugging, window, linux-kernel, monitoring

I'm programming something and I need debugging support on most operating systems (linux, windows, macosx).

This is what the program is supposed to do:
- fork a new program (platform specific program - like adobe reader on windows, but evince on linux)
- monitor for exceptions (handled and unhandled)
- execute a predefined function based on the exception

So basically I need some kind of a debugger, a library which I can use to make this possible. I would then start a debugger, start a program, and monitor for the exceptions.

It would also be great if I could execute & monitor for the exceptions over the network. So let's say my program is running on computer A and is connected to computer B (via ssh, RDP, whatever) and I would start a new program in computer B from computer A, and also monitor and react based on the exceptions from the computer B.

So my question is: is anything like that already written in form of a perl/python/whatever library or something similar. If it is, I would very much like to know about it.

Just to make this more clear: the linux only library call for this (just not supporing the network part) is **ptrace** system call.

Comment: Well, if you think you need some kind of "remote debugger" you may try the "gdbserver". But note that this will probably be a **huge** security hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gdb](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/)
There is a built in python debugger.pdb